# Create a new project in Tizen SDK

Tags: tizen

i have installed Tizen SDK in my Debian 64bit.

But when i try to create a new Tizen project i have this error:

```
The selected wizard could not be started.
```

Plug-in org.tizen.nativecpp was unable to load class org.tizen.nativecpp.wizards.TizenCppProjectWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.tizen.nativecpp (578).

Answer (score 0):

My first step would be checking which java runtime is used by default (it should be  oracle/sun).

Comment: the java runtime is ok! is oracle 1.7..but isn't the problem

Comment: Then please write some more information like which Debian release you are using, what SDK version you are using.